# C# How to fill entire window with text starting from (0,0) to (1,0) etc.?

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a single character of text which will go from top to bottom, go back to top and move over right by 1 character and repeat until the entire window is full of text. How do I achieve this, building from the code I've already created? Thanks.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < Console.WindowWidth; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < Console.WindowHeight; j++)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(".");
      Console.SetCursorPosition(j, 0);
    }
  }
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Change to `Console.SetCursorPosition(i, j);`.

Comment: I didn't think to change both values, thank you

Comment: Every `Console` method has inherent overhead since it essentially has to interop with the console itself. It would be more efficient to build a string of the same length as the console's width and then `Console.WriteLine` it the same number of times as the console's height.

Comment: Alternatively, just use a single string that is `Console.WindowWidth * Console.WindowHeight` characters long and print it with a single `Console.Write`.

Comment: For the main purpose of building this those are not an option. It has to look like it is coming down similar to rain. I've added an interval now.

Comment: Also consider switching to [Console.Write()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hebffx2d(v=vs.110).aspx) so your screen doesn't scroll when you write at the bottom.

Comment: @Alanay Building the entire string and printing to the console in a single operation would still be loads faster than what you're trying to do.